# Hibernate on merge attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property

Tags: hibernate, jpa, merge, one-to-one

Let's consider two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user")
    private UserDetails userDetails;

}

@Entity
@Table(name="user_details")
public class UserDetails {
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign",
        parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "user"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private User user;

    public UserDetails(User user) {
        this.user = user;
        user.setUserDetails(this);
    }
}
```

And given lines of code:

```
UserDetails details = new UserDetails(user);
session.merge(details);
```

It produces an error:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.app.domain.UserDetails.user]; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.app.domain.UserDetails.user]
```

I know that, when I use method save() instead of merge() it will work. However, ethod save() cannot automatically update already existing rows, while merge() can.

Comment: The PrimaryKeyJoinColumn, which doesn't seem right here and could be related to the issue. I suspect user_details should have a foreign key to User, in which case you could let it default or use the JoinColumn annotation.  If you meant to use the ID as the foreign key, you need to remove the generator annotation and look at using mapsId, add in JPA 2.1

Comment: Does it work when you do `UserDetails details = new UserDetails(user); session.merge(user);`?

Comment: Can you use update method here like session.update(details);?

Comment: @Ranjeet no, it doesn't work.

Comment: @RameshFadatare update() doesn't work as well.

Comment: @Chris you're right! That was the problem. Thanks!